# WAMP after MySQL

Tags: mysql, wamp

I had previously installed Developer default using MYSQl notifier. I have recently installed WAMP. Do I need to remove all connectors, documentation etc of the MySQL components, or only MySQL server, so that there is no clashes between these two?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are pretty familiar with MySQL it is probably a bad idea to try and run 2 instances on the same machine.

WampServer comes with MySQL as an integral part of itself, so I might suggest uninstalling your original MySQL Server.

However, if you have created any databases, I would Export those databases so you have a backup which you can then Import into the WAMPServers MySQL before doing the uninstall.